# View is hidden automatically and undesiredly when run in simulator

Tags: ios, uikit, storyboard

Screenshot:

[image: ss]

Attribute Inspector:

[image: properties of view]

Size inspector:

[image: Size inspector]

View Debugger:

[image: view debugger]

Although the devices showing in the editor and the simulator are the same, when running the app on the simulator, the view which shows the result is hidden automatically. In the other device sizes the behaviour is the same too. What causes this?

I controlled the constraints but nothing seems wrong to me and there is no error or warning.

As I understand, the FillProportionally attribute of stack view leads to set the height to zero. In the Apple documentation, it says:

> FillProportionally, make proportions according to views's intrinsic size

so probably for one reason result view intrinsic size is 0. But I couldn't resolve yet.

Comment: the properties are not that telling for layout. please show the size inspector of that view (alt+cmd+6)

Comment: try to set the vertical compression resistance priority to 751 (or higher than any other view). Alternatively, add a height constraint.

Comment: Use the View Debugger.

Comment: @bbjay Unfortunately it didn't work :/ But I also added view debugger ss , can you inspect that?

Comment: @matt I have added View Debugger ss

Comment: Great that you solved it. Giving the answer as an Answer is the right thing to do. Do _not_ edit the question to include the answer. A question is a question, an answer is an answer.

Comment: Sorry I am kinda new. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fill Proportionally in UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931958/fill-proportionally-in-uistackview)

Thanks to this answer, I was able to fix it. I changed 'fill proportionally' to 'fill' and set the height to match the view's intrinsic size. When the view's intrinsic size is zero, using 'fill proportionally' sets the height to zero as well.